# Google Analytics doesnt track any data

Tags: php, google-analytics

i am working on a custom Google Analytics implementation making use of direct utm.gif requests.

**The problem**:
Google Analytics doesnt track any data. Maybe because sth. is wrong with the parameters?

Thank's for helping

**`Sample: trackPage parameters`**

```
array(16) {
  [0]=>
  string(53) "http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmwv=4.5.7"
  [1]=>
  string(14) "utmn=474288553"
  [2]=>
  string(34) "utmhn=labs.domain.de%2Fphp%2Fga%2F"
  [3]=>
  string(16) "utmcs=ISO-8859-1"
  [4]=>
  string(11) "utmul=de-de"
  [5]=>
  string(7) "utmsr=-"
  [6]=>
  string(7) "utmsc=-"
  [7]=>
  string(7) "utmje=-"
  [8]=>
  string(7) "utmfl=-"
  [9]=>
  string(6) "utmr=-"
  [10]=>
  string(70) "utme=8%28userstatus%2Amyvariable%299%28nofan%2Amyvalue%2911%281%2A1%29"
  [11]=>
  string(14) "utmdt=Homepage"
  [12]=>
  string(16) "utmhid=441842675"
  [13]=>
  string(12) "utmp=home%2F"
  [14]=>
  string(17) "utmac=UA-123456-1"
  [15]=>
  string(191) "utmcc=__utma%253D186215409.1789216404.1265552708.1288611723.1288619999.26%253B%252B__utmz%253D186215409.1288619999.1.1.utmcsr%3D%28direct%29%7Cutmccn%3D%28direct%29%7Cutmcmd%3D%28none%29%253B"
}
```

**`Sample: trackEvent parameters`**

```
array(15) {
  [0]=>
  string(53) "http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmwv=4.5.7"
  [1]=>
  string(14) "utmn=240340321"
  [2]=>
  string(34) "utmhn=labs.domain.de%2Fphp%2Fga%2F"
  [3]=>
  string(10) "utmt=event"
  [4]=>
  string(16) "utmcs=ISO-8859-1"
  [5]=>
  string(11) "utmul=de-de"
  [6]=>
  string(7) "utmsr=-"
  [7]=>
  string(7) "utmsc=-"
  [8]=>
  string(7) "utmje=-"
  [9]=>
  string(7) "utmfl=-"
  [10]=>
  string(6) "utmr=-"
  [11]=>
  string(116) "utme=5%28permission%2Apublish_stream%2Agranted%29%281%298%28userstatus%2Amyvariable%299%28%2Amyvalue%2911%281%2A1%29"
  [12]=>
  string(16) "utmhid=364249414"
  [13]=>
  string(17) "utmac=UA-123456-1"
  [14]=>
  string(191) "utmcc=__utma%253D186215409.1789216404.1265552708.1288611723.1288620331.26%253B%252B__utmz%253D186215409.1288620331.1.1.utmcsr%3D%28direct%29%7Cutmccn%3D%28direct%29%7Cutmcmd%3D%28none%29%253B"
}
```

Comment: Hi fabian, any luck? I'm doing some server-side analytics tracking, ecommerce and trackPageView, and both are generally working, I'm setting less params than you, just utm(vw, n, hn, cs, r, p, ac, cc).

I am having one problem, about half of my server side pageviews are coming as (not set) for screen resolution, color depth, country etc.

Comment: I looked over the params and values you're sending, nothing jumps out at me.

Hmm, your utmcc looks slightly odd, you have "utma%253d" I think that value got encoded twice.  It should be "utma%3D". E.g. "%3d" is a "=".  If you re-encode "%3d" you get "%253d".

Answer (score 0):

This one is generated with another lib and it's working. But i can't find my fault?

```
array(14) {
  [0]=>
  string(53) "http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmwv=4.5.7"
  [1]=>
  string(15) "utmn=8893029624"
  [2]=>
  string(18) "utmhn=labs.domain.de%2Fphp%2Fga%2F"
  [3]=>
  string(7) "utmcs=-"
  [4]=>
  string(7) "utmsr=-"
  [5]=>
  string(7) "utmsc=-"
  [6]=>
  string(11) "utmul=de-de"
  [7]=>
  string(7) "utmje=-"
  [8]=>
  string(7) "utmfl=-"
  [9]=>
  string(14) "utmdt=Homepage"
  [10]=>
  string(6) "utmr=-"
  [11]=>
  string(10) "utmp=/home"
  [12]=>
  string(17) "utmac=UA-123456-1"
  [13]=>
  string(199) "utmcc=__utma%3D155417661.238248693.1267644354.1279870281.1279921084.8%3B%2B__utmz%3D155417661.1279824753.5.6.utmccn=(organic)%7Cutmcsr=google%7Cutmctr=facebook%20goole%20analytics%7Cutmcmd=organic%3B"
}
```